# Upgrading to RSA Authentication manager 8.0, server linux or windows?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, rsa

We're planning on upgrading to RSA authentication manager 8.0, and I'm wondering if there is any benefits installing this on a Linux server instead of a windows 2008 server. We want to run it with applience to vmware.
Where can I find more about requirements for 8.0 version?

We're uppgrading for 6.1 version, so it will be a big change, since this now runs on a windows 2003 server.

So now we're trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Thank you for any suggestions and information.

Comment: We have a sysadmin who is a Linux expert, so the Security is not somthing we worry about. We have both Linux and Windows servers running in Our structure. But I was wondering if there is any benefit of running RSA 8.0 on a Linux enviroment instead of Windows, someone told me that With a Linux server, the updates fro RSA communitry would automatically install on the server, but not on a Windows server? Is there any other reason to chose Linux before Windows on this type of Security management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which ever platform your company is more comfortable supporting is going to be the best option.  If you don't have anyone in house that is good at Linux then that wouldn't be a good option as you won't be able to secure the platform.  Same goes for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Linux is more secure, but it really comes down to what your sysadmins are managing and whether having a Linux machine will be an exception..

Comment: If there's no one at the shop that knows anything about Linux it isn't going to be very secure.  If you handed me a Linux box I'd be opening the thing up just so that I could get stuff working as I know nothing about Linux.  Saying that Linux is more secure totally depends on who's managing the server.

Comment: That's what I said.. depends on what your admins are adept at. Bottom line is Linux is more secure if both options are able to be supported.